# Rust error on dyn ToSql + Sync: Temporary which is freed while still in use

Tags: rust, tokio-postgres

I am working on a rust project that is using the following code

```
let mut container: Vec<&(dyn ToSql + Sync)> = Vec::new();
```

I have a variable `name` which is of type Option. I am getting this error when I execute the following snippet

```
if name.is_some()
{
   let addr: &String = &"a".to_string();
   params.push(&addr);
}
```

error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
|
56  |              let addr: &String = &"a".to_string();
|                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
57  |              container.push(&addr);
58  |         };
|         - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement

I am trying to figure out a way to extend the lifetime of the variable and fix this error keeping the structure intact.

Comment: Push `Box<dyn ToSql + Sync>` instead.

Comment: I am actually passing this vector to a tokio postgres query, which expects an array of type &(dyn ToSql + Sync). Passing the vector with each parameter as Box::new() might make the source code compilcated.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the life of the values created within the `if` block by assigning them to (otherwise uninitialized) variables declared outside the block.

```rust
let addr: String;
let addr_ref: &str;
if name.is_some() {
    addr = "a".to_string();
    addr_ref = &addr;
    params.push(&addr_ref);
}
```

The variables keep the `String` alive to the end of the outer scope, but are only used if the inner scope assigns to them.

Note that this will only work assuming that you're going to *use* `params` inside the outer scope here. If you want to, say, return it from the function, you'll need `Vec<Box<dyn ToSql + Sync>>` instead. But if you don't, then this lets you continue using `&dyn ToSql` and avoid extra boxing.